# Can't be resolved to a type

Tags: java

I have a service interface that reads thus

```
package services;

import domain.Items;

public interface IItemsService extends IService {

public final String NAME = "IItemsService";


/** Places items into the database */
public void storeItem(Items items);




/** Retrieves items from the database
 * 
 * @param category
 * @param amount
 * @param color
 * @param type
 * @return
 * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
 */
public Items getItems (String category, float amount, String color, String type) throws ItemNotFoundException, ClassNotFoundException;

}
```

And a factory that looks like this...

```
package services;
public class Factory {



public Factory(){}



@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public IService getService(String name) throws ServiceLoadException {
    try {
        Class c = Class.forName(getImplName(serviceName));
        return (IService)c.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ServiceLoadException(serviceName + "not loaded");
    }
}



private String getImplName (String name) throws Exception {
    java.util.Properties props = new java.util.Properties();
        java.io.FileInputStream fis = new java.io.FileInputStream("properties.txt");
            props.load(fis);
                fis.close();
                return props.getProperty(serviceName);
}
}
```

This should be really simple - but I keep getting two errors - IService cannot be resolved to a type (on both the factory and the service) and also an serviceName cannot be resolved into a variable error in the factory.  I know I am missing something simple...

Comment: Well, did you define IService? You didnt' show it to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the type error: if `IService` is not in the package `services`, then `IItemService` will not have access to it and you will need to `import some.package.name.IService`.

The second answer is simple: in the `getService` and `getImplName` methods, the parameter is named `name`. In the method bodies, you're referring to it as `serviceName`. You should probably change `name` to `serviceName` in each of them.

If, on the other hand, you're trying to access an instance variable, note that in Java you have to declare all instance variables before you can access (read from/write to) them. You would need to modify the class as such:

```
public class Factory {

    private String serviceName;

    public Factory () {}

    // other code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the second error is simple: *there isn't a variable called `serviceName`*. If you think there is, point to its declaration. I suspect you *meant* to use the parameter - in which case just change the parameter name to match the name you're trying to use:

```
public IService getService(String serviceName) throws ServiceLoadException 

...

private String getImplName (String serviceName) throws Exception
```

This was a pretty simple error - you should think about what bit of your diagnosis let you down in working it out for yourself. (You should also indent your code more sensibly, btw.)

As for `IService` being missing - we have no idea where `IService` is meant to be declared, which makes it very hard to help you on this front...